# Множество сайтов под разными доменами на одном скрипте

Tags: python, django

Есть задача на несколько типичных сайтов на разных доменах. Интересно реализовать без копирования проектов и приложений джанго, а на одном скрипте. Шаблоны и базы данных разные.

Нужен самый простой путь, не высоконагруженные проекты.

Answer (score 1):

[Документация Django](http://django.readthedocs.org/en/1.4.X/ref/contrib/sites.html)